# How best to use an owner class

Tags: c#

When writing programs i keep comming up against the same challanges where i try use an owner class to control and manage what happens in the created classes but I feel I'm off track with the whole philosophy.

For example i might want to create a device class that also has a serial port class. I want other parts application to use the serial port class directly but in order for the serial port class to function it will need to make calls to methods in the device class but not nessersarally methods i want to be public.

Are there better ways to go about this

Comment: You should create a class which manages the serial port. The Device class and the other can then communicate with that class. The SerialPort class then has to take care what to send/receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the SerialPort class should not make direct calls back to the owner, bad implementation. Use interfaces, like ISerialPort for SerialPort class that is implemented by DeviceClass. The DeviceClass creates the SerialPort class as private and exposes the interface. The interface implementation for DeviceClass intercepts and performs the comms to SerialPort providing the required info that is private for the Device to the SerialPort instance. Thus all comms to SerialPort is handled by the Device indirectly.

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to the approach I had taken whereby I would create a nested class of SerialPort within a partial class of Device. The SerialPort class would then be exposed via an ISerialPort interface. I guess I was just worried about the whole nested class approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make a public Init() method to call all necessary private methods in your device class, possibly using (optional) parameters to be flexible. This Init method will use/initialize the Serial port class.

Than you can use the device class in a normal way, i.e. using public methods to get/send information etc. Also here methods from the serial port class can be called, but the caller of the device class can be unaware of this.